# MySql one row from multiple select

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out how to have a row from a table:

I search in a range/conditions, and I need 7 columns out of it: max Price, min Price, last Price, (if and when Price>=x, so the first Price >=x and its time), (if and when Price<=y).

The table is:

```
id (int, key unique)
date (varchar, don't need it) 
price (decimal) 
unix (int, key) (unix time)
ck (int, key)
fk (int, key)
```

I tried a multiple select/join and it works, but if just one select is empty (maybe if Price won't be >=x) it returns the whole empty, I need a result back anyway...

```
SELECT *  FROM 
    (SELECT date , price as 'Sprc', unix as 'Sunx' 
    FROM prices WHERE
        (unix BETWEEN 1420185600 AND 1420192800) AND
        ck>0 AND fk=0 AND 
        price <= 1000 
    order by unix ASC limit 1) as tmp1
JOIN
    (SELECT date , price as 'TPprc', unix as 'TPunx'  
    FROM prices WHERE  
        (unix BETWEEN 1420185600 AND 1420192800) AND  
        ck>0 AND 
        fk=0 AND 
        price >= 100 
    order by unix ASC limit 1) as tmp2
JOIN
    (SELECT MIN(price) as 'min', MAX(price) as 'max'  
    FROM prices WHERE 
        ck>0 AND 
        fk=0 AND  
        (unix BETWEEN 1420185600 AND 1420192800) 
    order by unix ASC limit 1)  as tmp3
JOIN
    (SELECT date, price as 'last'  
    FROM prices WHERE 
        ck>0 AND 
        fk=0 AND 
        (unix BETWEEN 1420185600 AND 1420192800) 
    order by unix DESC limit 1)  as tmp4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the word `LEFT` in front of each of your join statements.

Doing so indicates that the query should return all rows from the first table regardless of whether or not it finds a matching row in the second table.

Comment: thanks for answering, I just added LEFT in front of each but got back a #1064 syntax error... (sorry I'm not expert ...)